# How do I bind to both a data binding and a property value in a style trigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to grey out some text when some piece of data is "Ignored", but I don't want the grey out to happen when the item is selected. (Specifically, in high contrast mode, setting the color to the grey value causes the text to be unreadable)

This was my first attempt to do that.

```
<Style>
<!-- .... -->
<Setter Property="Control.Foreground"
        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextColor}}" />
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <!-- Set gray text when not selected, and ignored. -->
            <Condition Property="ListBoxItem.IsSelected" Value="false" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding Ignored}" Value="true" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground"
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextColor}}" />
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This fails at runtime because `MultiDataTrigger` needs Binding to be set on its conditions. (At least, I think that's why it is failing.)

How can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upvoted Andrew's answer, I think you want to be binding to the `IsSelected` property of the `ListBoxItem`, using `RelativeSource`, although I'd try it this way:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="false" />
```

That worked for me, using a `Style` in a `ResourceDictionary`, and using it in a `ListBox` by setting the `ItemContainerStyle` property.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on where exactly you are using the Style, you can convert the first Condition to bind to the ListBoxItem.IsSelected property by using a RelativeSource binding.

Comment: This is being applied to `<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>`.

Comment: try this inside your first Condition:  Binding = {Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}

Comment: Also - you should capitalize 'True' and 'False' inside your conditions - it's standard in XAML, even though it's not standard for xml.  There are cases where it makes a difference.